# Laravel MustVerifyEmail doesn't exist?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am developing a web application using laravel.

I want to implement email verification via
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification

I modified my User model to use MustVerifyEmail interface:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use App\SecurityQustion;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
```

And I am getting the following error:

> Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail' not found

I verified in my vendor/laravel.../Auth/ folder and the file itself doesn't appear to be there.

---

To be noted:

- The Auth functionality works good, it was installed with `php artisan make:auth`, and the migrations generated were runned, so this is not the issue.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.5.44

Comment: That's because this functionality was introduced in 5.7.

Comment: Oh I understand, it appears this feature was only added in 5.7...

Comment: Out-of-the-box email verification was only added in Laravel 5.7 https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/releases

Comment: Yes it doesn't exist in 5.5 https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**: Upgrade your laravel project to use latest features, Here is how you can upgrade laravel project :-

Change this line in **composer.json** to upgrade,

```
"laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
```

Please take a backup before upgrading it to newer version (Safety measures)

Ref. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/releases#laravel-5.7

Comment: Updating laravel/framework and other dependencies worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you must upgrade to laravel 5.7 above